# Solve a system of symbolic equations in python sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Being new to sympy, I would benefit from a little help to put me on the rails... In the example below, how can I obtain the result for `G_S` from the `system` of two symbolic equations? The answer should be `G_S = S11 - S12 S21 / (1 + S22)`.

```
S11,S12,S21,S22 = symbols("S11 S12 S21 S22")
S = Matrix([[S11, S12], [S21,S22]])
a1,b1,a2,b2 = symbols("a1 b1 a2 b2")
In = Matrix([a1, b2])
Out = Matrix([b1, a2])

system = [Eq(Out,S*In), Eq(a2+b2,0)]
G_S = b1/a1
```

Olivier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the help given in the other answers, I summarize a satisfactory solution:

```
sol = solve(system, [a2,b2,b1])
G_S = sol[b1]/a1
G_S = factor_terms(collect(expand(G_S),'S11'))   # rearrange the expression
```

The `Sij` are viewed as coefficients while the `ai` and `bi` are viewed as variables. The system represents 3 equations and allows to solve for that number of unknow variables. We thus solve for `a2,b2,b1` and divide the `b1` solution by the `a1` unknown.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: there is probably a more elegant way to do this. I'm pretty new to SymPy myself.*

You just need to tell SymPy to actually solve the system of equations. Do all the steps just like you did, but right after you define `system` you need to tell SymPy to solve for `b1` and `a1`, then use those solutions to calculate `G_S`. (Note that `solve` returns a dict.)

**Edit**: even though we're only using the answers for `b1` and `a1` when we calculate `G_S`, we still need to tell `solve` to solve for all four variables `a1`, `b1`, `a2`, `b2` for it to give us the correct answer.

```py
system = [Eq(Out,S*In), Eq(a2+b2,0)]
soln = solve(system, a1, b1, a2, b2)
G_S = soln[b1]/soln[a1]
```

When I do this SymPy gives me the correct-but-still-ugly answer of `-(-S11*(S22 + 1) + S12*S21)/(S22 + 1)`. If I call `simplify(G_S)` I get the less-ugly-but-still-ugly answer of `(S11*(S22 + 1) - S12*S21)/(S22 + 1)`. That's the fun of doing symbolic math with a computer -- its idea of "simple" is never quite the same as a human's.

Comment: When I run what you say, i.e. pasting my code and then pasting your code, I get `G_S = (S11*(-S22*b2 + a2) + S12*S21*b2)/(-S22*b2 + a2)` and `simplify(G_S)` does not change anything. How comes that you got something different?
Also, by hand, I find the solution by solving for b1 and a2, and then calculating  b1/a1. However, `solve(system, b1, a2)` does not give a solution. Why?

Comment: Weird. I got the same behavior. I had edited some stuff out. Originally when I tried this I called `soln = solve(system, a1, b1, a2, b2)`, and then I attempted to "simplify" it into `soln = solve(system, a1, b1)`. But when I try it again, if I used the "simplified" version I get the same answer you just got, and if I call the longer version `soln = solve(system, a1, b1, a2, b2)` then it works. I will edit my answer above to correct this.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. Mathematically, I would tend to say that `solve(system, [a2, b2, b1])` is preferable because otherwise the system is overdetermined. Strangely, `solve(system, [a2, b2, b1, a1])` does not solve for `a1` and gives exactly the same result as `solve(system, [a2, b2, b1])`  (this is black magic to me).

Answer (score 0):

@Mr-Snrub has shown how to solve the equations. To get a nicer simplification you can try

```
>>> eq
-(-S11*(S22 + 1) + S12*S21)/(S22 + 1)
>>> factor_terms(collect(expand(eq),'S11'))
S11 - S12*S21/(S22 + 1)
```

The problem with non-target simplification is that the sum ends up getting expanded and lost. By letting `cse` capture that repeated expression of `S22 + 1` and expanding the `cse` expression, `e`, and backsubstituting the common expressions -- in this case, only 1 -- the expression you prefer is obtained:

```
>>> r,e=cse(eq)
>>> e[0].expand().subs(reversed(r))
S11 - S12*S21/(S22 + 1)
```

Comment: This works well! (but to a newbie like me, this looks like black magic)

Comment: You can always do these things manually, too. You understand that using expand will expand the numerator and denominator but you don't want the s22+1 to expand...so replace it with x, expand, and restore the original: `eq.subs(S22+1,'x').expand().subs('x', S22+1)`. Note that quotes are not necessary if you have already created a symbol x with `vars('x')`.